# Are NaN items in pandas groupby followed by aggregation including category column expected behavior?

Tags: python, pandas, aggregation

I aggregated a pandas DataFrame that contained a category column. The output contained several NaN's that I did not expect and don't understand. Example code:

```
import pandas as pd

d = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 1, 2, 2], 'b': [1, 1, 2, 2], 'c': [1, 2, 3, 4]})
d.astype({'b': 'category'}).groupby('a').agg({'b':'first', 'c':['mean', 'max']})
```

I get the following output:

```
      b    c     
  first mean  max
0     1  NaN  NaN
1     2  1.5  2.0
2   NaN  3.5  4.0
```

I would have expected the following output:

```
      b    c    
  first mean max
a               
1     1  1.5   2
2     2  3.5   4
```

Can somebody explain the NaN's?

The following two code variants, one without the category column and one without multiple aggregations of column c, give me the expected output.

```
d.groupby('a').agg({'b':'first', 'c':['mean', 'max']})
d.astype({'b': 'category'}).groupby('a').agg({'b':'first', 'c':'mean'})
```

I am using pandas 0.25.2 and python 3.7.4.

Comment: You have an issue with index alignment.  In the first variant, `b` will maintain the grouper keys as its index, so alignment happens, and in the second variant, `c` won't have a multiindex so the alignment happens.

Comment: However, looking through the code for `groupby`, I'm not sure if a categorical `dtype` not respecting as_index is indended.  I think it would be worth opening an issue to get a clear answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is [bug](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/13416), but possible solution is use function with [`Series.iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iat.html) for first value of group, because [`Series.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.first.html) working different:

> Convenience method for subsetting initial periods of time series data based on a date offset.

```
def first(x):
    return x.iat[0]

d = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 1, 2, 2], 'b': [1, 1, 2, 2], 'c': [1, 2, 3, 4]})
d = d.astype({'b': 'category'}).groupby('a').agg({'b':first, 'c':['mean', 'max']})
print(d)
      b    c    
  first mean max
a               
1     1  1.5   2
2     2  3.5   4
```

If use lambda function then get `<lambda>` string for second level of `MultiIndex`:

```
d = d.astype({'b': 'category'}).groupby('a').agg({'b':lambda x: x.iat[0], 'c':['mean', 'max']})
print(d)
         b    c    
  <lambda> mean max
a                  
1        1  1.5   2
2        2  3.5   4
```

Answer (score 2):

The start point of my explanation is to have (and compare the behaviour of)
**two** DataFrames:

- `d` - the **original** DataFrame,
- `d2 = d.astype({'b': 'category'})` - the **sibling** DataFrame,
  with *b* column changed to *Categorical*.

Create grouping of these both DataFrames:

```
gr = d.groupby('a')
gr2 = d2.groupby('a')
```

For now they look identical, e.g. if you run:

```
for key, grp in gr:
    print(f'\nGroup: {key}\n{grp}')
```

and the same code for *gr2*, you will get **exactly** the same result.

But the results become different, when you attempt to
**aggregate** *b* column.

When you run `gr.b.agg('first')` (on the original DataFrame), you will get:

```
a
1    1
2    2
Name: b, dtype: int64
```

The result is a *Series* and as expected from `d` content:

- for group of rows with *a == 1* the first value of *b* is *1*,
- for group of rows with *a == 2* the first value of *b* is *2*.

But if you run `gr2.b.agg('first')` (on the sibling DataFrame), you will get:

```
[1, 2]
Categories (2, int64): [1, 2]
```

The result is of *pandas.core.arrays.categorical.Categorical* type
and what is more important, there is **no relation** with grouping keys.

Instead, something acting **like** grouping keys are **consecutive numbers**
(starting form *0*).

You can confirm this, running `gr2.agg({'b':'first'})`
and you will get:

```
   b
0  1
1  2
```

An just this is the source of your problem.
When you run:

```
gr2.agg({'b':'first', 'c':['mean', 'max']})
```

joining aggregation of **both** *Categorical* and "normal" columns, then:

- the above **artificial** grouping key resulting from
  aggregation of *b*,
- is joined with **actual** grouping key from aggregation of *c*.

For (artificial) grouping key *0*:

- the value for *b / first* is *1* (see above),
- for *c / mean* and *c / max* there are no values, so the
  result contains 2 *NaN*s.

For grouping key *1*:

- for **artificial** key, the value for *b / first* is **2**,
- for **true** key, values for *c / mean* and *c / max* are
  **1.5** and **2.0**,
- but *Pandas* places all of them in **the same** row.

For grouping key *2*:

- there is no "artificial" grouping key with this value,
  so in *b / first* column there is *NaN*,
- for *c / mean* and *c / max* there **are** corresponding values,
  so they are printed there.

**Conclusion:** In case like this, it is not a good idea to convert
any column to *Categorical* type.

Use just **original** DataFrame, with "original" (non-Categorical) types
and you will get your expected result.

## Edit following comment as of 09:14:38Z

There is a contradiction between what you wrote in your post and in the
mentioned comment.

Your post contains write:

```
I get the following output:

      b    c     
  first mean  max
0     1  NaN  NaN
1     2  1.5  2.0
2   NaN  3.5  4.0
```

so the printout **does** contain *NaN* values.

But in the comment you wrote *I don't get any NaN*.

To verify this contradiction, I made the test again:

```
d = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 1, 2, 2], 'b': [1, 1, 2, 2], 'c': [1, 2, 3, 4]})
d2 = d.astype({'b': 'category'})
d2.groupby('a').agg({'b':'first', 'c':['mean', 'max']})
```

and got:

```
      b    c     
  first mean  max
0     1  NaN  NaN
1     2  1.5  2.0
2   NaN  3.5  4.0
```

just as in your post **with** *NaN* values.

Comment: This is now much clearer to me. Though, then I don't understand the output of `gr2.agg({'b':'first', 'c':'mean'})` anymore. Based on your explanation, I would expect a misalignment/mismatch between true and artificial index, yielding NaN's. But I don't get NaN's.

Comment: Yes, this is a misalignment. But I am surprised with "I don't get NaN's" in your comment. In your post there **are** NaN values in the output you got.

Comment: I understand with your explanation the NaN's in `gr2.agg({'b':'first', 'c':['mean', 'max']})`. But when I execute `gr2.agg({'b':'first', 'c':'mean'})` (difference is in aggregation of c), I don't get any NaN (but would have expected by your explanation).